# Piecewise function same as multi part function?

Tags: functions

As shown in attached graph,we have a multi part function. Can we also call it **piece wise function**?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The graph is that of [piecewise function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise). Said function also appears to be [piecewise linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_function). I'm unfamiliar with the term "multi part function", but Google seems to suggest that it's synonymous with piecewise function.